# css media query doesn't work on Sony Xperia Z smartphone

Tags: css, media-queries

I need your help, I face a problem with my css media query code.

I just wrote the following css media code

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {

    #content {
       width: 100%;
       margin: auto;
    }
    #recent_activities .act {
        width: 94%;
        padding: 3% 10px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        text-align: left;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        height: inherit;
    }
    #header_container
    {
        display: none;
    }

   #footer {
        width: 94%;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 3% 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

my problem is that the code works perfectly on the computer screen when I re-size the browser window but unfortunately it does not work on my smart-phone (Xperia Z).

Comment: do you have a `<meta name="viewport"...` tag in your html page?

Comment: No, could you help me about how to use it ?

Comment: Please provide us more code, like your HTML source. Also some screenshots would be fine, in order to give you decent feedback.

Comment: The Xperia Z has a resolution of 1920x1080 according to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Xperia_Z). Run a simple test: add a simple JS like `alert(window.innerWidth)` to see the width of your device. If the width is larger than the 900px you are setting as a max, the CSS will not be applied and that's the reason why it's not working

Comment: this is the link, it is just html page

haidar.ws/crm/public.html

Comment: @Mohammad try to put this in your `<head>` and try again: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">`

Comment: @GalV thanks, it worked perfectly, I will read about it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the following meta tag in the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Great answer! I was stuck on this for days... This only seems to be an issue on the Sony Xperia devices

Comment: it doesn't work for me but thank you for the possible solution